# How do you disable an object on first play in Unity using PlayerPrefs?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to hide a game object the first time the user plays the game. I've tried doing this by basing it off the high score - if a high score is not set or at 0, the object should not be active. No luck with that and then tried by just using a counter to set 'FirstPlay'.

I can get the if part to disable the object
but then the else does not seem to take effect.

Have tried the below in both Start and Awake. Any help appreciated.

One

```
public GameObject coinShopDisplay;
public void Awake()
{
    if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("FirstPlay", 0) == 0)
    {
        coinShopDisplay.SetActive(false);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("FirstPlay", 1); 

    }
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("FirstPlay")>=1)
    { coinShopDisplay.SetActive(true); }
}
```

Two

```
public GameObject coinShopDisplay;

// Start is called before the first frame update
public void Start()
{
    if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("FirstPlay", 0) == 0)
    {
        coinShopDisplay.SetActive(false);
    }
    else
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("FirstPlay", 1);
        coinShopDisplay.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Three

```
public GameObject coinShopDisplay;

// Start is called before the first frame update
public void Awake()
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("highscore", 0) >= 1)
    {
        coinShopDisplay.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
    {
        coinShopDisplay.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public GameObject coinShopDisplay;
    public void Start()
    { 
        if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("FirstPlay") == 0)
        {coinShopDisplay.SetActive(false);}
        else{PlayerPrefs.SetInt("FirstPlay", 1);coinShopDisplay.SetActive(true);}
    }
```

**This looking fine..**